# What branch of mathematics studies rubber band balls

Tags: general-topology

I'm making a rubber band ball and am trying to not make any of the rubber bands flip. This is possible with one revolution (simplest), three revolutions, five, etc.

Are there more than one way to wrap a rubber band around a ball three times without flipping the band?

What branch of mathematics would study rubber band balls in more detail?

Comment: Differential geometry or differential topology?

Comment: The answer depends on what you mean by "way".  If you are particularly rigid, there's infinitely many ways.  You could relax it to the study of immersions of the circle in the sphere, in which case there are exactly two ways, but you could cut that down to one if you are particularly fussy about what it means to wrap.  You can always get rid of "flips" by turning them into small loops.